# React: определение, что нажат Caps Lock или включена не английская раскладка клавиатуры

Tags: javascript, reactjs, события, клавиатура

хочу сделать такой функционал для поля для ввода (пароль)

если

1. включён Caps Lock, то информируется пользователь
2. если включена не английская раскладка клавиатуры, то информируется пользователь

С Caps Lock нахожу примеры, которые отслеживают по сути нажатие Caps Lock при уже работающем сайте при активном браузере, однако Caps Lock может нажиматься

1. до запуска сайта
2. после того, как пользователь переключился на другое приложение, а затем переключился обратно в браузер

подскажите, как можно отслеживать такие ситуации в том числе будучи неактивным

Что касается английской раскладки - то тут вообще без понятия как подступиться

Comment: никак - ты можешь только проверить что введено  и какая клавиша нажата

Comment: т.е. раскладка в общем доступна только по косвенным (и ненадежным) методам?

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под раскладкой? У js в браузере вообще нет доступов к системным настройкам. Все что можно - это подписаться на нажатие клавиш и посмотреть что нажато, и какие модификаторы.

Answer (score -1):

Проверить Caps Lock можно как-то так:

```
if (value === value.toLowerCase) {...}
```

ну или с помощью регулярки, как и наличие кириллицы

```
/^[a-z0-9]+$/.test(yourString)
```

Но это уже после введения текста. Как до этого уведомить, я не в курсе

**Отредактировано:**

Еще у KeyboardEvent есть метод getModifierState. Таким образом опять же только после ввода первой буквы произойдет проверка на капс лок

```
onKeyDown = (e) => {
  if (e.getModifierState('CapsLock')) {
    alert('CapsLock is enadled');
  }
};
```

Comment: Заглавную букву можно ввести с нажатым SHIFT.